# nginx proxying requests to wrong backend

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Why would going to https://robert.bob.com/norbert/ go to backend1 instead of backend2 with this configuration?

```
server {
    server_name robert.bob.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://robert.bob.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    ssl             on;
    ssl_certificate      conf.d/test_combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  conf.d/star.bob.com.key;
    ssl_client_certificate conf.d/gd_bundle.crt;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:!kEDH;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    server_name  robert.bob.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

    location / {
        auth_pam              "Danger Zone";
        auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
        proxy_pass http://backend1.bob.com:8080/;
    }

    location /norbert/ {
        auth_pam              "Danger Zone";
        auth_pam_service_name "nginx";
        proxy_pass http://backend2.bob.com:8080/;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've completely changed your question rendering my answer unrelated.  Don't do that please.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've changed your question completely my original answer (bottom) no longer applies.

But one reason that going to https://robert.bob.com/norbert/ goes to backend1 instead of backend2 could be because backend1.bob.com and backend2.bob.com resolve to the same IP on the machine running your nginx proxy.

I think this section may also be wrong (I'm not 100% on that), it may need the listen 80 directive.

```
server {
    server_name robert.bob.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://robert.bob.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

This is how I've done it and it works for all domains, but you can use the server_name directive if required for just one host.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

---

It's a reverse proxy if the URL in the browser doesn't change, otherwise it's a rewrite.

Something like the following minimal nginx config should work.

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location /a/ {
    proxy_pass http://server1:8080;
  }

  location /b/ {
    proxy_pass http://server2:8080;
  }

  location /c/ {
    proxy_pass http://server3:8080;
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry about the edits. I wasn't quite sure what I was asking for before. I appreciate your help. It is helpful!

This host resolves both backend1 and backend2 to their individual IPs.

I tried the listen and return 301 you suggested, but the result is the same. both / and /norbert/ go to backend1.

Comment: Try taking the trailing slash / off the end of the proxy pass.

Comment: Taking the / off the end of the proxy pass url results in: 

`{"message":"URI not found: /norbert/"}`